# Only activate component when a valid configuration can be bound in Apache Felix

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, karaf, declarative-services

We're using declarative services to create components. We have a hard requirement that the service provided by the component should be available only when a configuration exists and is valid. We also need the component (and service) to be immediately available when a valid config exists.

For requirement re: the existence of the config, we're using the setting:

`configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE`

For the immediate availability of the component, we're using the setting: immediate=true

For the validation of the config, we're applying a validation logic in the component activation method, and a ComponentException exception is raised if we find that the config is invalid.

The results we're getting in Karaf 4.0.8 are making sense, except that the service looks still available (listed by services ) while the component is not shown as ACTIVE by scr:components command.

Here's a sample code where the configuration is considered valid only when the 'count' property is <=10:

```
@Component(immediate=true, configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
public class MyTestComponent implements MyTestInterface {

    int count=0;
    public void sayHello() {
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            System.out.println("Hello!!");
    }

    @Activate
    public void activate(BundleContext context, Map<String,String> config) {
        count = Integer.valueOf(config.get("count"));
        if (count>10) {
            throw new ComponentException("Count should be <=10");
        }
        System.out.println("COUNT from config: " + count);
    }

    @Deactivate
    public void deactivate() {
        System.out.println("Component being de-activated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Little advice. It is hard to see what you are asking in your question. Often this will lead other people to vote to close your question with the reason: Unclear what is being asked. Try to be more precise with your questions. Update your post to make clear what you are asking.